# How to install ossbrowser?

Tags: ubuntu, alibaba-cloud, alibaba-cloud-oss

I need to download some files using the preset oss path, access key id, and access key secret. I downloaded the file for ubuntu from https://www.alibabacloud.com/help/doc-detail/61872.htm?spm=a2c63.p38356.b99.112.26f94e20idgreZ, however,  I am unable to install the browser.

Can someone guide me on how to install the oss browser?

I found no guide on installation and launching the browser on ubuntu.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

oss-browser doesn't come with a pre-built package. But manual installation is simple.
Download oss-browser from the release page:
https://github.com/aliyun/oss-browser/blob/master/all-releases.md
Extract the Zip archive:

```
unzip oss-browser-linux-x64.zip
```

Move the folder to a location:

```
sudo mv oss-browser-linux-x64/ /opt/
```

Create a desktop file:

```
vim ~/.local/share/applications/oss-browser.desktop
```

With the following content:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Type=Application
Encoding=UTF-8
Name=OSS Browser
Comment=Ossbrowser is a graphical management tool developed by Alibaba Cloud. It provides features similar to those of Windows Explorer. Using ossbrowser, you can view, upload, download, and manage objects with ease. 
Exec=/opt/oss-browser-linux-x64/oss-browser
Icon=/opt/oss-browser-linux-x64/resources/custom/icon.ico
Terminal=false
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes there is no official documentation from Alibaba Cloud for the installation guide for the **OSS Browser** at this time.

There are a few suggestions for your consideration.

You may do these 3 suggestions at the same time.

1. Log a new issue on this in the OSS Browser GitHub Repo.
   https://github.com/aliyun/oss-browser/issues
2. Open a new support ticket on this in your Alibaba Cloud console
   under Support and Services.
3. Post a new suggestion on the Alibaba Cloud Connect platform for the
   product team to review and adopt.
   https://connect.alibabacloud.com/suggestion/add

Hope this helps.